# Wait node.js until Logstash is ready using containers

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I have the following setup in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
....

logstash:
  container_name: logstash
  image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.2.4

node:
  container_name: node
  build:
    context: ./node/
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  depends_on:
    - logstash

....
```

I'm using the package `winston-logstash` to wire them together.

This is the transport layer:

```
const logstashHost = process.env.LOGSTASH_HOST || 'logstash'
const logstashPort = process.env.LOGSTASH_PORT || 5045

new (winstonLogstash.Logstash)({
  host: logstashHost,
  port: logstashPort,
  node_name: 'node',
  timestamp: true,
  max_connect_retries: 5,
  timeout_connect_retries: 1000,
})
```

And the pipeline configuration:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5045
  }
}
output {
  stdout{}
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
}
```

Using `docker-compose up` results in `Error: Max retries reached, transport in silent mode, OFFLINE`

If I manually start the server either using a large `setTimeout` or incrementing the number of connection retries it finally works. It works too if I start logstash and after a while I start node container.

The problem is that obviously this is not a good practice, I can't guess how long `logstash` will take to start, and the `depends_on` directive inside `docker-compose.yml` doesn't help at all.

I need a way to know when `logstash` is ready and start the `node` container after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker compose does not wait until a container is ready, it will only wait until it's running.

`depends_on` will only ensure that `logstash` launches before your node container, but again, this doesn't mean it will wait until it is ready.

You can either handle the checks yourself on node, or use a wrapper script. In docker-compose documentation, they recommend, [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)

You can read more on this in [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

---

### Custom wrapper

Your node container `command` can change from `node index.js` (or whatever you have), to `bash wait-for-logtash.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Or whatever command is used for checking logstash availability
until curl 'http://logstash:5045' 2> /dev/null; do
  echo "Waiting for logtash..."
  sleep 1; 
done

# Start your server
node index.js
```

Comment: You're `wait-for-it` link is broken.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks