# can't connect to redis through node app, both in dockers

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose, ioredis

I'm trying to connect my app to redis, but i get:

`[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED  127.0.0.1:6379`

when i do:

`docker exec -it ed02b7e19810 ping test_redis_1`
i've received all packets.

also the redis container declares:

`* Running mode=standalone, port=6379`

`* Ready to accept connections`

( i get the WARNINGS but i don't think its related:

`Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf`

`WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128`

this is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-service:
      build: .
      volumes:
        - ./:/usr/test-service/
      ports:
        - 5001:3000
      depends_on:
        - redis
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

DockerFile

```
 FROM node:8.11.2-alpine

 WORKDIR /usr/test-service/

 COPY . /usr/test-service/

 RUN yarn install

 EXPOSE 3000

 CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

app.js

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis();

redis.set('foo', 'bar');
redis.get('foo').then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

i've also tried with `redis` package but still can't connect:

```
 var redis = require("redis"),
     client = redis.createClient();

 client.on("error", function (err) {
     console.log("Error " + err);
 });
```

getting:

```
 Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that specific `docker-compose.yml` there is no `redis` on `127.0.0.1`, you should use `redis` as host, since services on the same Docker network are able to find each other using the service names as DNS.

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis({ host: 'redis' });
```

Furthermore, `depends_on`  does not wait for `redis` container to be ready before starting, it will only launch it first, so it is your job to wait before starting `app.js` or just handle that inside `app.js`

`io-redis` comes with a [reconnection](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#reconnect-on-error) strategy, so you may want to try that first.

You can see my answer here regarding that issue:

[Wait node.js until Logstash is ready using containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520698/wait-node-js-until-logstash-is-ready-using-containers/50521018#50521018)